# Binding multiple public IPs to one Hyper-V Virtual Machine

Tags: hyper-v, virtual-machines, windows-server-2012-r2

I have a Windows 2012 R2 with Hyper-V running. I have created an external Virtual Switch and a VM ( virtual machine). The VM has it's own public IP. I can ping that VM from a remote computer and it responds fine. However, when I bind another public IP to the VM's Network adapter -- that IP is not reachable from externally. My question is: Is it possible to bind multiple public IPs to a Windows 2012 R2 Hyper-V Virtual machine? If so, how?

Comment: Is the second ip address in the same subnet as the first? If not, is the second subnet being routed correctly?

Comment: you have probably some misconfiguration with network/default route/mask or routing problem. yes it is possible - more details needed

Comment: Hello joeqwerty -- yes they are in the same subnet.

Comment: @KonchiBash Have you been able to find a solution? I'm in the same situation, need to assign 4 public IP addresses to a Hyper-V machine.